# Python - Sampling rows from a data frame without replacement

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, sampling

I want to sample rows from a pandas data frame without replacement. What I mean is this. In each iteration of the for loop, I sample a certain number of rows from `COMBINED` without replacement. I want to ensure that over 50,000 iterations, I do not ever sample the same row again. My code below tries to solve this sampling problem, but I get errors.

`COMBINED`,`TEMP`, `MERGED`, `SAMPLE`, `SAMPLE_2` AND `PROBABILITY_GENERATED_POISSON` are data frames. `lst` is a list.

Please see my code below:

```
#FOR LOOP TO SAMPLE FROM COMBINED BASED ON NUMBER OF EVENTS PER YEAR
#AVOIDING REPEATED SAMPLING OF SAME EVENTS
for i in range(50000):
    #IF THERE ARE NO EVENTS FOR THAT PARTICULAR YEAR, THERE WILL BE NO EVENT NUMBER AND NO LOSS
    if PROBABILITY_GENERATED_POISSON.iloc[i,:].item == 0:
        lst.append(0)
    #IF THERE ARE MORE THAN 0 EVENTS FOR THAT YEAR, FOLLOW THE BELOW PROCESS 
    else:
        SAMPLE = COMBINED.sample(n = PROBABILITY_GENERATED_POISSON.iloc[i,:], 
                                 replace = False,
                                 weights = LOSS_EVENT_SAMPLE_PROBABILITY,
                                 axis = 0)
        SAMPLE['Sample'] = i
        #CREATE TEMP DATA FRAME WHICH CONSISTS OF ALL ROWS SAMPLED IN PREVIOUS ITERATIONS
        #except FUNCTION IS FOR ERROR HANDLING - IT PREVENTS THE LOOP FROM STOPPING MIDWAY
        try:
            TEMP = pd.DataFrame(lst)
            #PERFORM AN INNER JOIN - SELECTING COMMON ROWS FROM TEMP AND SAMPLE
            MERGED = TEMP.merge(SAMPLE, how = "inner")
            #AVOIDING DUPLICATION WITHIN LIST
            #IF THERE ARE NO COMMON ROWS (nrow(MERGED) == 0), THEN INPUT SAMPLE INTO lst
            if MERGED.shape[0] == 0:
                lst.append(SAMPLE)
            else:
                #IF THERE ARE COMMON ROWS (nrow(MERGED) > 0), THEN SAMPLE AGAIN, BUT AFTER EXCLUDING THE COMMON ROWS FROM 
                #THE COMBINED DATA FRAME. BY EXCLUDING THE COMMON ROWS, WE ENSURE THAT WE ARE NOT SAMPLING ROWS WHICH
                #WERE SAMPLED IN PREVIOUS ITERATIONS.
                COMBINED_2 = COMBINED.subtract(SAMPLE)
                SAMPLE_2 = COMBINED_2.sample(n = PROBABILITY_GENERATED_POISSON.iloc[i,:], 
                                 replace = False,
                                 weights = LOSS_EVENT_SAMPLE_PROBABILITY,
                                 axis = 0)
                SAMPLE_2['Sample'] = i
                lst.append(SAMPLE_2)
        except:
            continue
    
    print(i)
```

The error I get is attached with the picture.

I would like some feedback on my question.

Thank you.[image]

Comment: is .sample(50000, replace=False) what you need?

if not, can you explain can you provide a minimum example of data and algorithm to illustrate what is needed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Here are are two ways to solve:

1. solution using pandas `.sample` function

```
n = 50000
COMBINED.sample(n, replace=False)
```

2. solution using a simple algorithm that does the same thing as `.sample()`

```
# use the diamonds dataset to illustrate and test the algorithm
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

df_input = sns.load_dataset('diamonds')

df = df_input.loc[[]]
df_temp = df_input # this is where we're sampling from
n_samples = 1000
for _ in range(n_samples):
    sample = df_temp.sample(1)
    df_temp.drop(index=sample.index, inplace=True)
    df = df.append(sample)

assert((df.index.value_counts() > 1).sum() == 0)
df
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the error. `PROBABILITY_GENERATED_POISSON` needs to be a list.